# If-statement too nested?

Tags: python, django

I use the following code to check if the ticket should contain a discount or not. There are now three if-statements and I wonder if there is a better way to not make it less nested?

```
ticket_price = current_ticket.display_price
    discount_code_session = request.session.get(request.event.discount_code_cookie(), None)

    if discount_code_session:
        discount_code = Discount.objects.filter(
            code=discount_code_session,
            event=request.event.pk
        ).first()

        # Make sure discount_code exists
        if discount_code:
            discounted_tickets = discount_code.tickets.all()

            # Why not discounted_tickets: If discounted_tickets empty, then the
            # discount code is valid for all tickets.
            if not discounted_tickets or current_ticket in discounted_tickets:

                discounted_price, original_price = (
                    discount_code.calculate_discounted_value(ticket_price)
                )

                ticket_price_dict = {
                    'original_price': original_price,
                    'discounted_price': discounted_price,
                }
                return ticket_price_dict
    return ticket_price
```

After @richflow comments, I now have this code, where I think it's more clear:

```
ticket_price = current_ticket.display_price
    discount_code_session = request.session.get(request.event.discount_code_cookie(), None)

    if not discount_code_session:
        return ticket_price

    discount_code = Discount.objects.filter(
        code=discount_code_session,
        event=request.event.pk
    ).first()

    # Make sure discount_code exists
    if not discount_code:
        return ticket_price

    discounted_tickets = discount_code.tickets.all()

    # Why not discounted_tickets: If discounted_tickets empty, then the
    # discount code is valid for all tickets.
    if not discounted_tickets or current_ticket in discounted_tickets:

        discounted_price, original_price = (
            discount_code.calculate_discounted_value(ticket_price)
        )

        ticket_price_dict = {
            'original_price': original_price,
            'discounted_price': discounted_price,
        }
        return ticket_price_dict
    else:
        return ticket_price
```

Comment: what are the returns for the cases where your if conditions are false?

Comment: @richflow the `return ticket_price` scopes everything in case the if conditions are false

Comment: You can get rid of the "else:" at the end too, bring the last line out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deeply nested `if`s are a code smell, though not necessarily wrong.

In general, you want to fail fast with condition checks rather than nest them:

```
discount_code_session = xxx
if not discount_code_session:
  return ticket_price

discount_code = yyy
if not discount_code:
  return ticket_price

if discounted_tickets or current_ticket not in discounted_tickets:
  return ticket_price

#otherwise
do_the_things_here
```

You can also try posting over at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as that's probably a better place for this kind of question.

**Edit**

This really goes into code review territory, but to flesh out a more complete answer, here's what [this book](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/) as a guide to Python has to say (relevant bits to what you're asking):

> There are two main cases for returning values in a function... [one is]
>   the error cases ... or any other
>   reason for the function to not be able to complete its computation or
>   task.
>
> ...In this case, it is
>   better to return as early as the incorrect context has been detected.
>   It will help to flatten the structure of the function: all the code
>   after the return-because-of-error statement can assume the condition
>   is met to further compute the function’s main result...
>
> However, when a function has multiple main exit points for its normal
>   course, it becomes difficult to debug the returned result, so it may
>   be preferable to keep a single exit point...

I'm with the first argument. Others choose the second. Read the [whole thing](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/) as it provides more details to help you make a decision.

Comment: pylint will not like this - not would I.... A Method generally should only have 1 return statement.